# close custom Dialog android

Tags: android, spinner

I created a custom dialog with spinner and OK button. I have populated this spinner with some items and inflated the layout.If I click OK button dialog will dismiss. 
I set the spinner

```
spinner.performCLick();
```

is there is any way to get spinner selected item and to close the dialog without pressing OK button. I have tried

```
button.performclick();
```

but no use.

Comment: maybe post the code for the custom dialog and would help people understand it a little better.  Also the code where you want to get the spinner item and close the dialog (I assume it is on some other user action besides the ok press)

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry I am very new.. Ignore me

Comment: no apologies necessary, I just noticed you accepted an answer, so glad you got what you needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see my below **code** it may help you.

```
package com.Test_dia;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.Dialog;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.AdapterView;

import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.Spinner;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class Test_diaActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btn;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showalert();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void showalert() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Dialog dia = new Dialog(this);
        dia.setContentView(R.layout.dia);
        final String a[] = { "select one", "android", "java", "php" };

        Button btnok = (Button) dia.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Spinner spin = (Spinner) dia.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        btnok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dia.dismiss();
            }
        });

        spin.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, a));

        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (arg2 > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(Test_diaActivity.this,
                            "You Selected :" + a[arg2], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    dia.dismiss();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        dia.show();
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="click here" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**dia.xml**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:text="ok" />
```

This code is work for me perfectly ok.

enjoy....

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**  (removed previous non-suitable answer)

I'm going to assume that your issue is that using `setOnItemSelectedListener` is firing 'onItemSelected' on startup (thus selecting the first item in the spinner without any user input) and you don't want that.

If that is the case, try the following.

Set a class variable:

```
private int newSpinner = 0;
```

Then in the `setOnItemSelectedListener`:

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int pos, long id) {
            if (newSpinner != 0) {
                // Do your code thing here
                dismiss();
            } else {
               newSpinner++
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am not sure. but is there is any way to detect spinner item clicked

Comment: @user1336442 Yes, the answer I posted is how you detect a spinner item click...  You need to explain your problem more clearly.  Saying "it doesn't work" and "I'm not sure" is not helpful.  You obviously know how it's not working, or you wouldn't be posting that it's not working.  We're not asking why the code isn't working, we're asking what you are expecting to get and what you are getting.  I've edited my answer based on a guess of the problem you are having.  Let me know if that's not the issue (and what the issue actually is).